# jqxdatatable showDetails function automatic page switch if index doesn't exist

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqxgrid, jqxwidgets

I am using `jqxDataTable` plugin, I could able to show row details successfully if row index exists in current page, I don't know how to show row details if in case row index is in next page or any other page, I need some help to accomplish this task please someone help,  Please have a look on this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7ac5G/19/#fork)

**This is scenario**

Created datatable with 3rows per page

```
$("#dataTable").jqxDataTable({
  width: 632,
  source: dataAdapter,
  pageable: true,
  pageSize: 3,
  ....
  ....
  .. some more code
 });
```

**Button to show row details**

Two buttons to show row details, in which first one works since row index is in current page, second button doesn't.

```
 // Page 1 row - no issue
 $('#jqxbutton').click(function () {
        $("#dataTable").jqxDataTable('showDetails', 0);
 });

 // Page 2 row - don't know how to switch page automatically
 $('#jqxbutton2').click(function () {
       $("#dataTable").jqxDataTable('showDetails', 5);
});
```

Hope my question is clear, let me know if you need more detail about the question.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to go to a certain page, you can do: `$("#dataTable").jqxDataTable('goToPage', 2);` where `2` is the page index.

So, to `showDetails` of an item on another page, you can do:

```
$('#jqxbutton2').click(function () {
    var item = 6;
    var pageSize = $("#dataTable").jqxDataTable('pageSize');
    $("#dataTable").jqxDataTable('goToPage', parseInt(item/pageSize));
    $("#dataTable").jqxDataTable('showDetails', item);
});
```

Comment: Yes solved, thanks a ton, any idea to get currently selected row dom element ? after calling showDetails function.